# I am looking for a story from Omni about sentient aircraft of different types interacting in the atmosphere

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a story in (I believe) one of those Ellen Datlow OMNI science fiction collections about sentient aircraft of different types (with different duties) flying around in the atmosphere and interacting with each other. I am vague on the details but there were no human characters. I read it in the 1990s but I think it was published in the 1970s or 1980s. Does this ring a bell for anybody? I’d really like to read it again.

EDIT: It may have been published in the Chrysalis anthologies instead of OMNI based on my memory of what anthologies I had around the house at the time I read the story.

Comment: I would like to read that.

Comment: I have the Omni anthologies numbers 1 to 5 and the story isn't in any of those.